# What could be electable positions in the senate of organized crime?

Tags: politics, modern-age, ancient-history, crime, class-structure

So I am constructing a decisional body for the world of organized crime in my near future setting. I am basing this on many things, among them the ancient roman senate.

Only the most senior members of each mafia faction get a seat in the senate which is about 300 seats in total. Among the normal senators I want there to be electable positions, where representatives from each faction get to make decisions on the inner workings of the organization.

The only one I've managed to come up with so far is "Censors" which admit new seated members of the senate and vet them in matters of "moral purity". What could be other positions like this that would elevate someone's influence, or give them extra responsibility within this criminal body?

Comment: Obviously, the Speaker, or *Princeps Senatûs* in Latin. Then, of course, chairing and participating the [various committess](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/committees/) (budget, appropriations, security, banking, resources, armed forces etc.). And if you are throwing around names of Roman magistratures, you have quaestors, aedils, and various legates... Please take the [tour] to understand how this site works; as it is, the question doesn't seem to call and allow for *one* answer.

Comment: I think it's hard to answer this in a way which is not opinion based. And why would organized crime use elections, when guns are way faster in deciding promotions and dismissals?

Comment: Fundamentally, organized crime isn't a government that's about governing the masses, it's a corporation that's about making money. So why not structure your offices around those of a major corporation, i.e., CEO, CFO, COO?

Comment: Hi mdlsvensson, I have to agree with AlexP and L.Dutch that this question is currently primarily opinion-based and hard to answer nicely with SE's one-question/best-answer format. I've voted to place your question on-hold so you can have a chance to edit it without getting swamped by unhelpful answers - feel free to ping me when you've edited it and I'd love to retract my close vote or cast a reopen one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robbery, fencing, protection and extortion, termination, prostitution, gambling, smuggling and distribution, loansharking, lobbying, counter-intelligence, and conflict resolution.

Robbery being the theft of items.

Fencing is the selling of items previously stolen.

Extortion is gaining money or other resources in exchange for threats.  Protection is when the threat is violence perpetrated by the one making the threat.  Blackmail is also a specific kind of extortion.

Termination is assassination (for hire) or enforcement (of the rules or for breaking agreements).

Prostitution is sex for hire.

Gambling is where one places money on a possibility.  If the possibility occurs, you get money back.  If not, you don't.  This could be a sporting event, a card game, a roulette wheel, or any other possibility.

Smuggling and distribution is the transport and sale of illegal items.

Loansharking is the offer of loans, often to people with little collateral or income but at high rate of interest.

Lobbying is the attempt to influence the legal government.  It may include bribes, blackmail, or extortion.

Counter-intelligence would be the search for people who might be sharing information with law enforcement.

Conflict resolution is when two or more mafia members disagree.  They can bring their dispute to conflict resolution where it can be mediated or arbitrated.

It would also be reasonable to have a budgetary committee, just as a regular legislature would.  You may also consider giving the jobs more mafia names like Boss Pimp, Viglord, whacking, hooking, etc.